# I am using Koolwired.Imap to retrieve attachments via iMAP.

Tags: c#, imap

I am using Koolwired.Imap to retrieve attachments. The following is the code that I have written.

using K = Koolwired.Imap;

```
    public void GetAttachmentsTest(string thread, string selectFolder, string fileName)
    {

        K.ImapConnect connect = new K.ImapConnect(Global.host);

        K.ImapCommand command = new K.ImapCommand(connect);

        K.ImapAuthenticate auth = new K.ImapAuthenticate(connect, Global.username, Global.password);
        connect.Open();
        auth.Login();

        K.ImapMailbox mailBox = command.Select(Global.inbox);
        mailBox = command.Fetch(mailBox);

        K.ImapMailboxMessage mbstructure = new K.ImapMailboxMessage();

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {

                    int mailCount = mailBox.Messages.Count;

                    if (mailCount == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("no more emails");
                        break;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < mailCount; ++i)
                    {
                        mbstructure = mailBox.Messages[mailCount - 1];
                        mbstructure = command.FetchBodyStructure(mbstructure);

                        for (int j = 0; j < mbstructure.BodyParts.Count; ++j)
                        {
                            if (mbstructure.BodyParts[j].Attachment)
                            {
                                //Attachment
                                command.FetchBodyPart(mbstructure, mbstructure.BodyParts.IndexOf(mbstructure.BodyParts[j]));

                                //Write Binary File
                                string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
                                FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempPath + mbstructure.BodyParts[j].FileName, FileMode.Create);
                                int length = Convert.ToInt32(mbstructure.BodyParts[j].DataBinary.Length);
                                fs.Write(mbstructure.BodyParts[j].DataBinary, 0,length);
                                fs.Flush();
                                fs.Close();

                            }
                        }

                    }



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("T1 " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("T1 " + ex.StackTrace);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("T1 " + ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

I am getting error on the statement:

int length = Convert.ToInt32(mbstructure.BodyParts[j].DataBinary.Length);

and

fs.Write(mbstructure.BodyParts[j].DataBinary, 0,length);

and the error is:

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 characters, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

The above code breaks down at the lines shown when there is only 1 attachment.

If there are more than one attachment:

Then the code breaks down on line

mbstructure = command.FetchBodyStructure(mbstructure);

and the error is:

Invalid format could not parse body part headers.

I am soo close to getting this assignment taken care of. Could any one please help me.

I would also like to know how to delete the emails once I retrieve them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem
If anyone cares about, I solved it downloading the latest source code for the library from codeplex.
Once compiled, it works with no change. Looks like they have fixed it.

Also for deleting an email, just mark it for deletion:
command.SetDeleted(n, true); //-> Where n is the message number.

If is an IMAP connection, actually you have to expunge the deleted mails to complete the deletion.

command.Expunge();

Hope it helps someone.